# managedQuery always returns the same result

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contentprovider

In my onItemClick method I have:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Uri formula = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Formulas.CONTENT_URI, id);

    Cursor formulaCursor = managedQuery(formula, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    formulaCursor.moveToFirst();

    searchBar.setText(formulaCursor.getString(formulaCursor.getColumnIndex(Formulas.TITLE)));

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, formula));
}
```

Now the problem is that everytime it is called, the managedQuery **ALWAYS** returns the same result. I selected all the items in my database and the text for the `AutoCompleteTextView` is **ALWAYS** the same. I debugged it and found out that `Uri formula` is exactly what I want to it be, with an id of 3. But `Cursor formulaCursor` is not. So the problem is the managedQuery. But I see nothing wrong with it?

Comment: have you checked the content provider?

Comment: Oh ok, I found the problem in the ContentProvider. So that counts an an answer. Please put that in the answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely in the ContentProvider, so I suggest you check that.